# Implement two stacks using one array

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I still don't know WHERE to implement the second Stack.  Am i supposed to make another class?  I'm not quite sure how to finish up.  I'll keep searching.  Any help would be appreciated!  I also can't tell if my pop() method is working or not.  I printed out the stack.
Output:
true
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
false

```
public class twoStack {
    int maxSize = 10;
    int top;
    int top2;
    int arr[];

    public twoStack(int x) 
    {
        maxSize = x;
        arr = new int[maxSize];
        top = 0;
        top2 = maxSize;
    }

        //push pop empty peek
    public boolean empty()
    {
        if(top == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean empty2()
    {
        if(top2 == maxSize)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void push(int x)
    {
        if (top<maxSize)
        {
        arr[top] = 10;
        top++;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("Stack overflow");
        }
    }
    public void push2(int x)
    {
        if(top2<0)
        {
            arr[top2] = 0;
                    top2--;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Stack Overflow");
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public Object pop()
    {
        if(!this.empty())
        {
            int temp = (int) this.peek();
            arr[top-1]=(Integer) null ;
            top--;
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public Object pop2()
    {
        if(!this.empty2())
        {
            int temp = (int) this.peek();
            arr[top+1]=(Integer) null;
            top++;
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public Object peek()
    {
        if (!this.empty())
        {
        return arr[top-1];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public Object peek2()
    {
        if(!this.empty2())
        {
            return arr[top+1];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}



//mainstack
package twoStack;

import java.util.Stack;

public class mainStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//MM(main method)
        Stack<Integer> myStack= new Stack<Integer>();
        System.out.println(myStack.empty());
        myStack.push(5);
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
        myStack.push(10);
        System.out.println(myStack.pop());
        myStack.push(15);
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
        myStack.push(20);
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
        myStack.push(25);
        System.out.println(myStack.pop());
        myStack.push(30);
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
        myStack.push(35);
        System.out.println(myStack.peek());
        myStack.push(40);
        System.out.println(myStack.empty());






    }

}
```

Comment: write your tests with expected outcome.  Use a debugger to step through your code and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: _Many_ things are wrong with your code, it's difficult to decide where to begin. Such as: push `E` into an array of `int`s; no array creation anywhere; no concrete class shown (only an abstract one); ... it goes on and on.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik HI!  You led me in the right direction, thanks.  I found another book and now I am able to implement one full stack that works.  I don't know how to put together my second stack from the same array.  Also I don't know how to edit my question to show my update.  Sorry, I'm very new to this!!

Comment: _You can give all the odd indexes to one stack and all the even indexes to another_

Answer (score 0):

If you have one array of maximal size, two stacks are possible: as a stack grows from a fixed position in some direction and shrinks there too. The start position is fixed.

- pick a fixed bottom index for both stacks
- start the first stack from that bottom index upwards ++
- start the second stack from that bottom index downwards --

Use the full unallocated room, that is ++ and -- modulo the array size.
If both stack pointers meet, both stacks are full.

*I wonder whether I have told too much. Maybe just that a stack might grow upwards and downwards, and around (modulo), and has a fixed start.*

Comment: Oh!  That makes sense.  I will work on it and give an update tonight.  Thank you @Joop Eggen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class TwooStacksInAnArray {

    int[] array;
    int headOne,headTwo;

    public TwooStacksInAnArray(int n){
        array=new int[n];
        headOne=-1;
        headTwo=array.length;

    }

    public void pushX(int data){
        if(headTwo-headOne>1)
            array[++headOne]=data;
        else
            System.out.println("No space to fill data on stack1 ");
    }
    public void pushY(int data){
        if(headTwo-headOne>1)
            array[--headTwo]=data;
        else 
            System.out.println("No space to fill data on stack2 ");

    }
    public int popX(){
        if(headOne>-1)
            return array[headOne--];
        else {
            System.out.println("underflow stack1");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public int popY(){
        if(headTwo<array.length)
            return array[headTwo++];
        else{
            System.out.println("underflow stack2");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public boolean isEmptyX(){
        return (headOne==-1);
    }
    public boolean isEmptyY(){
        return (headTwo==(array.length));
    }

}


public class stackDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TwooStacksInAnArray twostack=new TwooStacksInAnArray(10);
        twostack.pushX(10);
        twostack.pushY(9);
        twostack.pushX(100);
        twostack.pushY(99);
        System.out.println("Poped element from stack 1: "+twostack.popX());
        System.out.println("Poped element from stack 2: "+twostack.popY());

    }

}
```